# Proxy In Curl Not Working Via Exec, But Does In Command line

Tags: php, curl, proxy, debian

so I am trying to make a curl using a random proxy from my proxy list text file I got.

Here is where I pulled the file from so you can get some context: http://orcahub.com/proxy-list/

It's just a txt file with a list of proxies.

Anyway I have a script which formats the curl request with a random proxy

When I just echo the format and then copy and paste that output into command line it works perfectly but when I execute I get a strange error.

```
sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
sh: -c: line 16: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Here is my current code

```
    $f_contents = file("cleanedxml4.txt");
    $line = $f_contents[array_rand($f_contents)];
    $data = $line;

    $pieces = explode(" ", $data);
    $woah = $pieces[0];
    $loah = $pieces[1];


        $f_contents = file("proxies_265.txt");
    $line = $f_contents[array_rand($f_contents)];
    $data = $line;

    $format = 'curl '.$loah.' -d \'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<methodCall>
<methodName>pingback.ping</methodName>
<params>
 <param>
  <value>
   <string>'.$url.'</string>
  </value>
 </param>
 <param>
  <value>
   <string>'.$woah.'</string>
  </value>
 </param>
</params>
</methodCall>\'';
$data = preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $data);
$format = $format . " --proxy " . $data . " -m 5";

$format = 'bash -c "exec nohup setsid ' . $format . ' > /dev/null 2>&1 &"';
exec($format);
//echo $format . "\n\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm, what's the bright idea of xml'ing your code so much? Here's what worked for me on my varsity server (no curlopt support):

```
exec('curl -s --connect-timeout '.$this->_connect_timeout.' -x '.$ip.':'.$port.' '.$this->_target_url.' > '.$hide.' 2>&1');
```

As can be seen, I save the output to a hide file on the server, which suits my scraper needs ([my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38322901/does-my-curl-proxied-scraper-make-me-invisible)). Hope this helps, tho a bit of a latecomer.